# what's the best way to find the element occurs in other map value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I try to find the element in the map values that also occurs in other values.

```
{
  1: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  2: ["a", "c"],
  3: ["c", "d"],
  4: ["a", "c"]
}

=>

{
  "a": [ 1, 2, 4 ], // a occurs in the map which key are 1/2/4
  "b": [ 1 ],
  "c": [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
  "d": [ 1, 3 ]
}
```

My implementation is:

```
map<int, set<string>> map1 = {
  { 1, set<string>{"a", "b", "c", "d"} },
  { 2, set<string>{"a", "c"} },
  { 3, set<string>{"c", "d"} },
  { 4, set<string>{"a", "c"} },
};

map<string, set<int>> map2;

for (const auto& [id, str_set] : map1) {
  for (const auto& s : str_set) {
    if (map2.count(s) == 0) {
      map2[s] = std::set<int>{id};
    } else {
      map2[s].emplace(id);
    }
  }
}
```

Looks like it's not efficient. So is there any other way to make this faster?
Or is there any appropriate data structure/algorithm to process those data as I want?

Comment: `Looks like it's not efficient` why?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I just don't like nested-for

Comment: aside: you don't need the `if`, `map2[s].emplace(id);` does the correct thing in both cases

Comment: [Is your question answered?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

- Use unordered map and unordered set. Average case constant time search.
- You can trade off space for more speed. Create a boolean matrix key vs value. O(1) search.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to get "faster", and you can make some assumptions about the input that 1) keys are all numeric and simply count up from 1, and 2) you only have single letters for values, then you can fit the whole (lowercase) alphabet into the bits of an int, and you can use a vector.

But if that's going overboard, I agree with previous answer, a hash table is better than a map (so use unordered_* versions of map and set).  Better than a set is vector (in this case).  You could use a vector of char as a set, with the letter as the index, and set a 1 to indicate "present".  This is like the bitset version stored in an int above, but in a real container, which may be more palitable.

Further, this code of yours:

```
if (map2.count(s) == 0) {
  map2[s] = std::set<int>{id};
} else {
  map2[s].emplace(id);
}
```

Is better written:

```
map2[s].emplace(id);
```

Note: for the maps and sets (and unordered maps and sets) operator[] will create the element if it's not there, so your work to initialize the set is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Boost libraries, you can use [`boost::bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) to combine both of your maps.

```
boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>, boost::bimaps::multiset_of<std::string>> map;
map.insert(1, "a");
...
map.insert(4, "c");
```

You can then lookup by number with `map.left` and by string with `map.right`

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to get "faster", and you can make some assumptions about the input that 1) keys are all numeric and simply count up from 1, and 2) you only have single letters for values, then you can fit the whole (lowercase) alphabet into the bits of an int and use that as a set.  With a vector of such ints, you could build your output by scanning the vector and test for bits and if present, add it to the output bitset.  No hashing, no allocations, no tree balancing, nearly zero page faults, prefetcher friendly, a straight O(1) with minimal footprint and virtually no indirection except to the vector's storage, which should be in cache.

But if that's going overboard, you should at least consider a hash table instead of a map (so use unordered_map and unordered_set).  But even better than a set is vector (in this case), since your keys are alphabet letters, you can pre-size a vector to just 26, and subtract 'a' from the character and use that as the index, and a value of 0 or 1 to indicate presence.

Further, unrelated to the above, this code of yours:

```
if (map2.count(s) == 0) {
  map2[s] = std::set<int>{id};
} else {
  map2[s].emplace(id);
}
```

Is better written:

```
map2[s].emplace(id);
```

Note: for the maps (and unordered maps) operator[] will create a default constructed element if it's not there, so your code to initialize the set is unnecessary and adds overhead.